# pgrouting with WMS

Tags: wms, pgrouting, html

I able to successfully perform pgrouting using WMS but I am looking to show the cost (the length) on the web page  (not only the line on the map but the length of the line) somewhere in an HTML div element next to my map.

I am I supposed to create a table out of the query and use PHP to access them. Any idea?

Comment: There is not really enough information in the question to provide a good answer. We need to know more details about how the solution looks like so far.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give more details, how you're using WMS. If you are referring to the [pgRouting workshop Geoserver chapter](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/geoserver.html), then you could do the following modification to the SQL query to return also the length as attribute:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(route.geom) AS geom, sum(route.l) AS length FROM (
    SELECT geom, ST_Length(geom) AS l FROM pgr_fromAtoB('ways',%x1%, %y1%, %x2%, %y2%
) ORDER BY seq) AS route
```

Now you can use `length` as a label for your route, or you could use a WMS FeatureRequest to query for it.